# Compile oracle invalid_objects ..... Wondering if this is right approach

Tags: oracle, object, compilation

```
 /* Formatted on 23/08/2011 12:42:42 (QP5 v5.163.1008.3004) */ 
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE COUNT_N_COMPILE AS    

 ERR_MSG        VARCHAR2(100);    
 COUNT_ERRORS   NUMBER := 0;    
 A              NUMBER := 0;  
 B              NUMBER := 0;   
 C              NUMBER := 0;    
 D              NUMBER := 0;

    CURSOR CUR_LOOP    IS
       SELECT OWNER, OBJECT_NAME, OBJECT_TYPE
         FROM DBA_OBJECTS
        WHERE OBJECT_TYPE IN
                 ('PACKAGE',
                  'PACKAGE BODY',
                  'VIEW',
                  'INDEX',
                  'PROCEDURE',
                  'FUNCTION',
                  'MATERIALIZED VIEW',
                  'SYNONYM')
              AND OBJECT_NAME NOT IN ('%$%')
              AND STATUS != 'VALID'; 
BEGIN   
 <GENERIC_CODE.DROPIFEXISTS (USER, 'COUNT_N_COMPILE_TABLE'); --drops if the table exists

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE COUNT_N_COMPILE_TABLE
                     (
                     OWNER VARCHAR2(300),
                     OBJECT_NAME VARCHAR2(300),
                     ERROR_STORED VARCHAR2(3000)
                     )
                     LOGGING 
                     NOCOMPRESS 
                     NOCACHE
                     NOPARALLEL
                     MONITORING';

    FOR CUR_REC IN CUR_LOOP    LOOP
       BEGIN
          CASE
             WHEN CUR_REC.OBJECT_TYPE IN
                     ('VIEW', 'INDEX', 'PROCEDURE', 'FUNCTION')
             THEN
                A := A + 1;

                EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
                      'ALTER '
                   || CUR_REC.OBJECT_TYPE
                   || ' "'
                   || CUR_REC.OWNER
                   || '"."'
                   || CUR_REC.OBJECT_NAME
                   || '" COMPILE';
             WHEN CUR_REC.OBJECT_TYPE = 'MATERIALIZED VIEW'
             THEN
                B := B + 1;

                EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
                      'ALTER '
                   || CUR_REC.OBJECT_TYPE
                   || ' "'
                   || CUR_REC.OWNER
                   || '"."'
                   || CUR_REC.OBJECT_NAME
                   || '" COMPILE';
             WHEN CUR_REC.OBJECT_TYPE = 'SYNONYM'
             THEN
                C := C + 1;

                EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
                      'ALTER '
                   || CUR_REC.OBJECT_TYPE
                   || ' "'
                   || CUR_REC.OWNER
                   || '"."'
                   || CUR_REC.OBJECT_NAME
                   || '" COMPILE';
             WHEN CUR_REC.OBJECT_TYPE = 'PACKAGE'
             THEN
                D := D + 1;

                EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
                      'ALTER '
                   || CUR_REC.OBJECT_TYPE
                   || ' "'
                   || CUR_REC.OWNER
                   || '"."'
                   || CUR_REC.OBJECT_NAME
                   || '" COMPILE';
             ELSE
                D := D + 1;

                EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
                      'ALTER PACKAGE "'
                   || CUR_REC.OWNER
                   || '"."'
                   || CUR_REC.OBJECT_NAME
                   || '" COMPILE BODY';
          END CASE;
       EXCEPTION
          WHEN OTHERS
          THEN
             ERR_MSG := SUBSTR (CUR_REC.OBJECT_TYPE || '  ' || SQLERRM, 1, 100);
             DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (ERR_MSG);
             COUNT_ERRORS := COUNT_ERRORS + 1;

             INSERT
               INTO COUNT_N_COMPILE_TABLE (OWNER, OBJECT_NAME, ERROR_STORED)
             VALUES (CUR_REC.OWNER, CUR_REC.OBJECT_NAME, ERR_MSG);
       END;    
       END LOOP;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('PROC, FUNCTION, INDEX, VIEWS   ' || A);   
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('PACKAGES    ' || D);    
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('MATERIALIZED VIEW    ' || B);    
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('SYNONYMS   ' || C);  
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (' TOTAL NUMBER OF ERRORS    ' || COUNT_ERRORS);    
     COMMIT; 
END;
```

/

Comment: I would add an ORDER BY so that packages are compiled before bodies.

Comment: `BEGIN
   FOR EACH_ROW IN CUR_REC
   LOOP
      BEGIN
         DBMS_UTILITY.compile_schema ('' || EACH_ROW.OWNER || '');
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN OTHERS
         THEN
            ERR_MSG :=
               SUBSTR (EACH_ROW.OBJECT_TYPE || '  ' || SQLERRM, 1, 100);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (ERR_MSG);
            COUNT_ERRORS := COUNT_ERRORS + 1;

            INSERT
              INTO COUNT_N_COMPILE_TABLE (OWNER, OBJECT_NAME, ERROR_STORED)
            VALUES (EACH_ROW.OWNER, EACH_ROW.OBJECT_NAME, ERR_MSG);
      END;
   END LOOP;
END';

Comment: You can find different techniques here: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/RecompilingInvalidSchemaObjects.php   Please note that the "custom script", which resembles your code, is incomplete and that several object types need to be added to it.

Answer (score 4):

you could use :

```
exec dbms_utility.compile_schema( 'YOURSCHEMAHERE' )
```

also see: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:637156098168

Comment: If an uncompiled object is called, the caller will get an exception and Oracle will compile the object. Many programs do not handle these exceptions gracefully, so it is considered good practice to recompile any invalid objects after you have run any DDL statements.

Comment: +1; however, if you have inter-schema dependencies, the utl_recomp package or the utlprp script may be better choices. See the link provided by @Klas above.

Comment: thanks for the info  correct me if i am wrong you have to b sys to use ult_recomp package.